# WooCommerce custom coupon discount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, price

I am trying to change the default WooCommerce coupon discount to a function where it **adds** the discount price to the total cart price. So instead of subtracting the discount it should add it up to the price.

I found that this is done in the [**`includes/class-wc-cart.php`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html) file, in a function called: 
[**`get_discounted_price`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1877) and [**`woocommerce_get_discounted_price`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1918)

I tried to add a filter to accomplish the above but it is not working quite well:

```
function custom_discount($price) {
     global $woocommerce;
     $undiscounted_price = $price;
     $product = $values['data'];
     $discount_amount = $coupon->get_discount_amount( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_calc_discounts_sequentially', 'no' ) ? $price : $undiscounted_price, $values, true );
     $discount_amount = min( $price, $discount_amount );
$price  = max( $price + $discount_amount, 0 );
  return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 'custom_discount', 10);
```

Anyone who can help me out on this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you search around about adding fees instead of using coupons for this? please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a thing that works is to set a negative coupon discount, like -10:)